# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'dict'

Tags: python

Trying to get this code to sort topological, but I get the error mentioned in the topic. How do I solve this?

PS: I do also have a method for adding edges and variables.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.edges = defaultdict(lambda: [])
    self.variables = {}  



def sorted_nodes(self):

    indegree = [0]*self.variables
    
    for i in self.edges:
        for j in self.edges[i]:
            indegree[j] += 1

    Q = []
    for i in range(self.variables):
        if indegree[i] == 0:
            Q.append(i)

    count = []

    L = []

    while Q:
        start = Q.pop()
        L.append(start)

        for i in self.edges[start]:
            indegree[i] -= 1
            if indegree[i] == 0:
                Q.append(i)
        
        count += 1

    if count != self.variables:
        return False
    else:
        return L
```

Comment: you can't multiply `dict` with a list

Comment: You probably intend to do: `indegree = [0] * len(self.variables)` and also `if count != len(self.variables):`

Comment: `self.variables` is dictionary. Maybe you wanted to create an array of `0s` of length of dictioary

Comment: FWIW, `defaultdict(lambda: [])` can simply be `defaultdict(list)`